# Creating a concept that is convertible to tuple without specifying the types

Tags: c++, type-conversion, tuples, c++-concepts

I have a class `student_t` that is convertible to `std::tuple` as specified from the `operator std::tuple<...>`:

```cpp
struct student_t {
 private:
  std::size_t age;
  std::string name;
  double gpa;
 public:
  constexpr operator std::tuple<std::size_t, std::string, double>() {
    return { age, name, gpa };
  }
};
```

I also have to create `convertible_to_tuple` concept that is convertible to tuple:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
concept convertible_to_tuple = std::convertible_to<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

It seems to work **when I specify the template arguments**:

```cpp
static_assert(convertible_to_tuple<student_t, std::size_t, std::string, double>);
```

However, when I create an arbitrary number of structs with different types for each data member, I do still need to explicitly specify them (otherwise the result is `convertible_to_tuple<student_t>` into `std::convertible_to<student_t, std::tuple<>>`) which is not good when I simply deduce the parameter that has type convertible to `std::tuple` which is not possible:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr void test(convertible_to_tuple<Ts...> auto) {}

// test:
convertible_to_tuple<std::size_t, std::string, double>(student_t{});
convertible_to_tuple(student_t{}); // not working
```

My reason that I shouldn't specify the template arguments from the concept is that I'm creating a function `to_tuple` which converts any tuple-like, arrays, and *is convertible to tuple* into `std::tuple`, where it is defined as:

```cpp
template <typename TupleLike>
constexpr decltype(auto) to_tuple(TupleLike&& t) {
  // solution: create own to get the array size
  using indices_ = std::make_index_sequence<[] consteval -> std::size_t {
    if constexpr (std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<TupleLike>>) {
      return std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<TupleLike>>;
 // } else if constexpr (...) { // convertible to `std::tuple`
    } else {
      return std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<TupleLike>>;
    }
  }()>;

  return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    if constexpr (std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<TupleLike>>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::forward<TupleLike>(t)[Is]...);
   // } else if constexpr (...) { // convertible to `std::tuple`
      } else if constexpr (qualified_tuple<std::remove_reference_t<TupleLike>>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleLike>(t))...);
      }
   // let's say the concept `qualified_tuple` is already defined.
    }(indices_{});
  }
```

Which seems to work with:

```cpp
int arr[2] = {4, 8};

[[maybe_unused]] auto t0 = to_tuple(arr);
[[maybe_unused]] auto t1 = to_tuple(std::array{1, 2, 3});
[[maybe_unused]] auto t2 = to_tuple(std::make_pair(true, nullptr));
```

The only problem is that I couldn't currently use the concept from the `constexpr if` because the template arguments are required to be specified.

Comment: FWIW, if you ditch the implicit conversion operator and use a named function like `to_tuple` or `as_tuple`, it's trvial to check for the presence of that functon.

Comment: It is impossible to check that something is convertible to *some* tuple, without specifying which tuple.

Comment: Rephrasing @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., I think you need an existential quantifier (exists T such that X holds), but concepts only give you a universal quantifier (for all T, X holds).

Comment: @Elazar Concepts give you neither actually.